# Randomly delete rows with condition R (aka rdeleteIf)

Tags: r

I have data frame x:

```
Button TrackNo  NextTime
 54    G155 2011-04-29 19:20:04
 50     H54 2011-04-29 19:25:41
 54    G157 2011-04-29 19:47:58
```

I need to delete say 30% (uniformly) of rows which have `button==54` (i.e.). How am I to do it?

I know how to delete with condition, say `a <- x[x[,1]==54,]`
And I know how to delete randomly, say `i <- runif(1,length(x)); a <- x[,i]`

But how to do it at the same time?

Comment: you cannot do it in the same time because those are two operations - certainly there are ways to achieve this in a singe line expression.

Comment: x[-sample(which(x[, "Button"]==54), .3*sum(x[,"Button"]==54)),]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@shadow  already answered in the comments with a one liner, but here's a work flow of how you can approach these things in the future. Once you understand this, you'll be writing one liners like @shadow in no time.

```
# generate some fake data (the kind you should provide when asking questions)
mydf <- data.frame(button = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), var1 = runif(100))

find.button.5 <- mydf$button == 5 # find row numbers where button == 5
perc.30 <- round(sum(find.button.5) * 0.3) # find 30% of button 5
button.5 <- which(find.button.5 == TRUE)
sampled.30 <- sample(button.5, perc.30) # row numbers of 30% of button 5
mydf[-sampled.30, ] # in your final output, include all but the 30%

> nrow(mydf[-sampled.30, ])
[1] 93
```

Notice that the rows from `sampled.30` are missing in your final output.

Comment: the resulting dataframe still has 100 rows?

Comment: @Berkan Are you measuring the number of rows are you looking at the last row number?

Comment: sorry, I assumed `mydf <- mydf[-sampled.30, ]` and was checking `nrow(mydf)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations! It's a bit confusing that nrow not equals last row number indeed. Finally I got it!

Comment: @user3031053 It would help if you considered that row numbers are actually row names. They  could easily be "row1-row100".